# how to subtract fixed number of days from a provided date by the user in android studio?

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

e.g. if the user fills in the date and there is a spinner consisting of three options i.e. 70,90 & 45. So if the user fills in the date and selects for example 70 & clicks submit then 20 days should be subtracted from the date filled by the user and the result should be shown i.e. the result will the date 20 days before the date filled in by the user. If selects 90 then 30 days before and so on... (java code)
[the ui image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMfnm.jpg)

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/backBtn7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Back"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.915" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/input1"
    android:layout_width="222dp"
    android:layout_height="49dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Shipment Date"
    android:inputType="date"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.532"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.096" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="220dp"
    android:layout_height="47dp"
    android:text="Lead Time"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.529"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/input1"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.063"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/submitBtn2"
    android:layout_width="223dp"
    android:layout_height="53dp"
    android:text="Submit"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.539"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spinner1"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.074" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/tv_result"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Java Code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_p_c_d_calculator);
    backBtn7 = findViewById(R.id.backBtn7);
    submitBtn2 = findViewById(R.id.submitBtn2);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("PCD Calculator");
    tv_result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_result);
    input1 = findViewById(R.id.input1);
    spinner1 = findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    submitBtn2 = findViewById(R.id.submitBtn2);


    submitBtn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });



    tv_result.setText("PCD: ");


    String[] users = { "70", "90", "45" };
    Spinner spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, users);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spin.setPrompt("Lead Time");
    spin.setAdapter(adapter);


    backBtn7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    });
    

}
```

}

Comment: What have you tried? Please include all relevant code to help provide a specific answer.

Comment: for the moment i haven't tried anything specific because I am not able to understand how to execute and proceed.

Answer (score 1):

## `LocalDate#minusDays`

You can use [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) from the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) package.

You can create `LocalDate` instance by using `LocalDate#of` static method:

```java
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2021, 4, 5); // Apr 5, 2021
```

If your date is input as a String, you can use `LocalDate#parse` method with DateTimeFormatter, for example:

```java
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("2021/04/05", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd")); // Apr 5, 2021
```

And finally, having `LocalDate` instance you can use a good bunch of methods for manipulations with dates:

```java
    LocalDate dateMinus30Days = date.minusDays(30);
```

For details, you can have a look at [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) or, for example, at this [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-date-time-intro).

Comment: I am sorry but the solution is not clear at all

Comment: @OLezhko FYI, Stack Overflow uses a variant of [*Markdown*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) for editing page content. You can use backticks as alternative to HTML *code* tags. I changed a few in this Answer, as an example.  See [*Markdown Help*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) page. Thanks for participating in Stack Overflow.